# How to make UITableView scroll both horizontally and vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I don't know How to make UITableView scroll both horizontally and vertically as Kickstarter ios app. Would you please explain briefly how can they do both way? Thank you.
Tab scroll horizontally

[image]

Tab scroll vertically

[image]

P/s: sorry, my reputation point is so low that i cannot embed the image.

Comment: Please don't share an image link from outside web pages. Instead, include the images into your question so we don't have to click on the link to see the image.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know how to simulate a UICollectionView using a UITableView??

Comment: To ozgurv, sorry, i want to include the images but the system doesn't allow me because my point is so low. To Hot Licks, yeah, the tabs could be scrolled horizontally as UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Moreover, if you swipe up or down, it will change to a different collection of tabs.

Comment: do you want to make tableview horizontally/ vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two different levels to the two directions of the "table view". The vertical scrolling is some sort of paginated table/scroll/collection view; this can be accomplished using a table view, a scroll view, or a collection view. [Here's a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28118403/1857279) on how to do vertical paging in a scroll view. Within each page, it looks like a `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

That is simply a vertical UIScrollView with paging enabled. Each page is populated with a horizontal UICollectionView.